# Почему функция извлекает только последний ключ (music), почему циклом не идет по всем, чтобы вычислить и вывести результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
let summary = 0;
let s = 0;
let key;

function period(guests, views, time) {
  for (key in browser) {
    summary += browser[key].guests * browser[key].time;
    s += browser[key].views * browser[key].time;
  }
  console.log(`${key}: Общее количество просмотров - ${s} `);
}

const browser = {
  movies: {
    guests: 300,
    views: 250,
    time: 24
  },
  pictures: {
    guests: 500,
    views: 200,
    time: 18
  },
  articles: {
    guests: 700,
    views: 400,
    time: 12
  },
  games: {
    guests: 900,
    views: 800,
    time: 27
  },
  music: {
    guests: 700,
    views: 650,
    time: 48
  }
}

period(browser);
```

Comment: Так ты поставил вывод в консоль после цикла....странно ожидать чего-то другого

Comment: *"функция извлекает только последний ключ"* --- это неправда

Comment: если законсолить в цикле, то подсчёт неверный

Comment: ну ты определись что тебе нужно: выводить каждый ключ или общую сумму.... общую сумму выводи после цикла, а ключи - в цикле

Comment: общее количество посетителей и просмотров по формуле посетители(просмотры) * время
считает верно он значения только из первого ключа

Comment: Похоже ты сам не понимаешь что ты считаешь........ судя по твоему коду ты считаешь суммы со всех ключей..........если ты не этого хотел, то и написана у тебя ересь в итоге

Comment: А считает он правильно. Что написал, то и считает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что ожидается что-то подобное:

```
for (key in browser) {
    let views = browser[key].views * browser[key].time;
    console.log(`Количество просмотров по ключу ${key}: ${views}`);

    summary += browser[key].guests * browser[key].time;
    s += views;    
}

console.log(`Общее число просмотров: ${s} `);
```